# setTimeout 0 and blocking function issues in Firefox

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, settimeout

I came across a situation were a button event handler calls a function, that may take a couple seconds to complete depending on the input. Once the function completes, the output will show up in a grid. 
The function is completely client side. Right before the function is running I add a css class to the grid wrapper div that basically just shows a 'loading' gif/animation.

This works fine in Chrome, but not in Firefox and IE 11.
Below is an oversimplified version of how I achieve this with javascript setTimeout 0.

```
$('#calc').on('click', function(){
  $('#container').addClass('loading');
  calculate(10, function(res){
    $('#result').text(res);
    $('#container').removeClass('loading');
  });   
});

//represents my long running function
function fib(n) {
    if(n<2) {
    return n;
  }
  return fib(n-2) + fib(n-1);
}

//will be called by click handler
function calculate(n,cb) {
    setTimeout(function(){
    var result = fib(n);
    return cb(result);
  },0)

}
```

As you can see I use setTimeout 0 in calculate(n,cb) to give the browser the ability to show the 'loading' animation before the function starts and then remove it when it is done. 
However, this does not work in Firefox. 
What are some other options for me to achieve what I am trying to do?
I am using jQuery here, but the actual project I am working on is using Angular5. But the idea should be the same.

Here is a jsFiddle to show what I am trying to do. Using the loading animation by Mattln4D (thanks)

https://jsfiddle.net/alabianc/qL5zggh7/

If you want to see some actual good result, run it with 40 as an input in calculate, but no more than that!

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Works fine in firefox for me if I increase timeout delay. Only tried  200 but that's not a lot of time

Comment: FYI, there's no point in using `return` in a timeout function.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you set the timeout = 0, it is so fast to browser can show the loading animation. When I try to change timeout = 10 or 100, I can see the loading animation show on both of chrome, ff.